# install .net framework 4.7.2 in docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, dockerfile, .net-framework-version, .net-4.7.2

I'm new to .Net Environment, I'm trying to implement docker here for my firm. They were using 4.5 earlier so I used the following statement in my dockerfile:

```
RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
```

Now, I want to do the same for framework 4.7.2 - I thought it will work if I run the statements like :

```
RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-472-ASPNET ; \
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net472
```

But it's not working this way instead shows the following error :

```
Install-WindowsFeature : ArgumentNotValid: The role, role service, or feature
name is not valid: 'NET-Framework-472-ASPNET'. The name was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-472-ASPNET ; Install-WindowsFeat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (NET-Framework-472-ASPNET:Strin
   g) [Install-WindowsFeature], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NameDoesNotExist,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager
   .Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand
```

Please help me with the same. I am really stuck and can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i searched for a few things online and i found out that there is one solution that if i mention to install chocolatey on powershell inside my docker file. This reference, I have received from the [this post](https://anthonychu.ca/post/dockerizing-aspnet-4x-windows-containers/) by anothony chu:

so i used:

```
# Install Chocolatey
RUN @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$env:ChocolateyUseWindowsCompression='false'; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
RUN powershell add-windowsfeature web-asp-net45 \
&& choco install dotnet4.7 --allow-empty-checksums -y \
```

in my docker file and now all works fine and good.

Comment: I used the same solution and stucked at Installing dotnetFX for long. Do you have this problem and how did you solve it ?

Comment: @csamleong - I have fixed this problem with the above-mentioned solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Installing the NET-Framework yourself, you could use

> FROM microsoft/aspnet

or

> FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2

to use an image with dotnet framework already installed.

or whatever version you need.

See https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/
for all the images on docker hub

Comment: I'm also using IIS in the same image, can I mention to FROM statements? as in one will be-FROM microsoft/iis and another will be one mentioned by you, is it allowed?

Comment: you can use multiple FROM statements, see https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

by compiling your code and copying the artifacts from the result of one stage to a new stage, you can use multiple base images.

Comment: you could also use COPY to get what you need from a specific, even external image e.g., 
COPY --from=microsoft/iis:latest . .

Comment: I'll try the same. and will surely be coming back to thank you if it works for me.

Comment: It isn't a working man! It shows the error - 'manifest for microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2 not found'.

Comment: perhaps it is 
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk