# How to set proper version of SDK in dockerfiler

Tags: c#, docker

Im trying to build docker image for my console application. Here is my dockerfile:

**dockerFile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.slm ./
COPY test/test.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore 
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build as publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.dll"]
```

Result in docker:

> #14 1.122 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1229,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/src/test/test.csproj]

As you can see, I need .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2. I tried to change sdk:7.0 to 4.7.2 but seems like it doesnt exist. How can I download required versions of SDK to my docker image?

> [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:4.7.2:
> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:4.7.2: not found

**EDIT1:**
I changed "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0" to "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019". Now I can download file but the new problem appears:

> [build 1/8] FROM
> mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019@sha256:03ea0e7adfe4d13f665e569baa093b1a3155a451151f0183cd7b54668e8fa025:
> ------ failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): link /Files/Program Files/common files/Microsoft
> Shared/Ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/common
> files/Microsoft Shared/ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui: no such file or
> directory

Comment: which version of .net fwk are you using in your application?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Check: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime/?tab=description .  Read about Version Compatibility.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145354/install-net-framework-4-7-2-in-docker

Comment: I changed "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0" to "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019". Now I can download file but the new problem appears (edit question)